# How to fix "fetch failed" in Svelte?

Tags: typescript, svelte, sveltekit

I have 2 files in local

The code in +page.svelte:

```
<script lang="ts">
import type { PageData } from "./$types";
import { generations } from "./generations";

export let data: PageData;

</script>

{#each  data.monsters as monster (monster.url)}
    <h1>{monster.id}: {monster.name}</h1>
{/each}

{

#each  generations as generation (generation.id)}
    <h1>{generation.name}</h1>
    <p>Games: {generation.games.join(', ')}</p>
    <p>Main Region: {generation.main_region}</p>
{/each}
```

The code in +page.ts:

```
    import type { PageLoad } from './$types'
type IndexMonster = {
    name: string
    url: string
}

export const load  = (async ({ fetch }) => {
    const response   = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20')
    const json       = await response.json()
    const monsters   = json.results.map((monster: IndexMonster) => {
        const splitUrl  = monster.url.split('/')
        const id        = splitUrl[splitUrl.length - 2]
        return {
            name: monster.name,
            url: monster.url,
            id,
        }
    })
    return {
        monsters: json.results
    }
}) satisfies PageLoad
```

And I get the following error:

> 

TypeError: fetch failed

> ```
> at fetch (D:\Documents\Ty\THE BIM FACTORY 4.7.2022\Code\WepApp\- js-pokedex-sveltekit\node_modules\undici\index.js:109:13)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Object.eval [as fetch] (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/fetch.js:27:10)
> at async eval (/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/runtime/server/page/load_data.js:195:18)
> at async load (D:/Documents/Ty/THE BIM FACTORY 4.7.2022/Code/WepApp/- js-pokedex-sveltekit/src/routes/+page.ts:9:23)
> ```

PLEASE PLEASE HELP ME FIX THIS ERROR, I'M A SVELTE NEWER!

The result I want when finished will look like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1yin9.png)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the URL for the API endpoint you are trying to access is correct and that the API is running properly.

Comment: My API URL works fine on the web
https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon?limit=20